# There is a typo in the authentication documentation

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

There is a typo on [this documentation page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).

It says "The explcit OAuth 2.0 flow" but it should say "The **explicit** OAuth 2.0 flow".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next build will push a correction to the auth documentation.